# R command for counting duplicates

Tags: r

I would like to get the sum of duplicates. For example,

```
No.   MRN   Bicycle   
1.    010      1
2.    011      1
3.    011      1
4.    012      0
5.    013      1 
6.    014      0
7.    015      1
8.    015      1
9.    015      1

1 is yes 
0 is no
```

May I know r code that **MRN 011 has 1 bicycle. NOT 2**.(**MRN 015 has 1 not 3**) And I would like to know total number of bicycles answer as *4*). NOT *7*. Please show me how to put command in R. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `table` to find the 'MRN's that have duplicates.

```
+(table(df1[-1])>1)[,2]
# 10 11 12 13 
# 0  1  0  0
```

If we need the total sum, just wrap it with `sum`

```
sum(table(df1[-1])>1)
#[1] 1
```

---

If the intention is to find whether there are `any` 'Bicycle' in each of the 'MRN'

```
+(table(df1[-1])>0)[,2]
#10 11 12 13 
#1  1  0  1
```

and its `sum` is 3.

Comment: May i know if the duplicates are not only two and sometimes 3 or 4 or 5

Comment: @MyintWin  The code will take care of that if I understand what you commented